# AS400ConnectionPool in Spring

Tags: spring, connection-pooling, ibm-midrange

I have a question that can I use AS400ConnectionPool in Spring if then pls provide me the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can... I have never seen that class, but looking at the [API](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/iseries/v5r1/ic2924/info/rzahh/javadoc/com/ibm/as400/access/AS400ConnectionPool.html) this is pretty straithforward:

```
<bean id="as400ConnectionPool" class="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400ConnectionPool">
    <property name="maxConnections" value="128"/>
</bean>
```

Now you can simply inject the pool into your services:

```
@Autowired
private AS400ConnectionPool testPool;

//...

AS400 newConn = testPool.getConnection("myAS400", "myUserID", "myPassword", AS400.COMMAND);
```

It is even easier with Java configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class As400Config {

    @Bean
    public AS400ConnectionPool testPool() {
        // Create an AS400ConnectionPool.
        AS400ConnectionPool testPool = new AS400ConnectionPool();
        // Set a maximum of 128 connections to this pool.
        testPool.setMaxConnections(128);
        // Preconnect 5 connections to the AS400.COMMAND service.
        testPool.fill("myAS400", "myUserID", "myPassword", AS400.COMMAND, 5);
        return testPool;
    }

}
```

Note that you cannot easily call `testPool.fill()` in XML configuration.

Comment: Thanks Tomasz Nurkiewicz actually the main purpose of my question is calling the testPool.fill(). If I cannot provide the username and password in the configuration file then it doesn't helpful to me.

Comment: @user1230211: so use `@Configuration` approach and inject properties from a file to that class (it is possible). But I think the best approach is to create a thin wrapper around `AS400ConnectionPool` that handles authentication for you (especially if user name/password are static for the whole application). And please be more specific when asking a question.